# XSLT - Checking for a substring

Tags: xslt, substring

I have two XSLT variables as given below:

```
<xsl:variable name="staticBaseUrl" select="'https://www.hello.com/htapi/PrintApp.asmx/getGames?contentId=id_sudoku&uniqueId="123456"&pageformat=a4'" /> 

<xsl:variable name="dynamicUrl" select="'https://www.hello.com/htapi/PrintApp.asmx/getGames'" />
```

How to check whether the second string (dynamicUrl) is a substring of the first string (staticBaseUrl) or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To check if one string is contained in another, use the [`contains`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/OutputOverview/function_contains_frame.html) function.

Example:

```
  <xsl:if test="contains($staticBaseUrl,$dynamicUrl)">
    <xsl:text>Yes!</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
```

**Update:**

For case-insensitive contains, you need to first convert the two strings to the same case before calling `contains`. In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `upper-case` function, but in XSLT 1.0 you can use the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if
        test="contains(translate($staticBaseUrl,$smallcase,$uppercase), translate($dynamicUrl,$smallcase,$uppercase))">
        <xsl:text>Yes!</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @dogbane : Thanks for your valuable help.But the message box does not show.

Comment: @dogbane : What can I do to check it in case-insensitive manner.

Comment: @1355 Try using `contains(upper-case($staticBaseUrl), upper-case($dynamicUrl))`. This will only work if you are using xslt2.0.