# XPath for key value pairs where key has a dynamic part?

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I get the values for

1. cookie1
2. cookie2
3. cookie3_www.abc.com (only cookie3 name is constant and www.abc.com is dynamic whatever it is coming in query parameter for domain in request)

For the following XML:

```
<Map>
   <mapData>
      <entry>
         <key>cookie1</key>
         <value>656fdhh</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>status</key>
         <value>True</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>cookie3_www.abc.com</key>
         <value>gsdfg464</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>cookie2</key>
         <value>dfdfssdf</value>
      </entry>
   </mapData>
</Map>
```

Please let me know how to write XPath to get these 3 field values.

---

### Update

I wrote this to get the value for `cookie1` and `cookie2` as below.

```
<xsl:variable name="cookie"><xsl:value-of select="$result/Map/mapData/entry[key and key='cookie1']/value"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="cookie1"><xsl:value-of select="$result/*/*/entry[key and key='cookie2']/value"/></xsl:variable>
```

Here `result` is the variable which store the output of the service call ex whole output XML.

**I am not able to find a way to get the value of `cookie3_www.abc.com` as this value is dynamic, only `cookie3` part remains same -- other part are dynamic.**

Please suggest how to get this value.

Comment: How? First you learn XPath: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/  that's your job, as is writing the code. We (maybe) just try to help fix whatever you did end up writing.

Comment: Hi Marc, I have already tried to get the values i am able to get the values for cookie1 and cookie2 but not able to get the value for "cookie3_www.abc.com" as this value is dynamic,only cookie3 part remain same other parts is dynamic.

Comment: xpath selectors allow substring matches. you can search for what amounts to `cookie3*` if necessary.

Comment: Is this work <xsl:variable name="cookie1"><xsl:value-of select="$result/*/*/entry[key and key='cookie3*']/value"/></xsl:variable> ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336954/xslt-checking-for-a-substring

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
/Map/mapData/entry[starts-with(key,'cookie3')]/value
```

will return the `value` in the same `entry` as the `key` that starts with `cookie3`.